# Python DataFrame display single column value

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Using  below json data, trying to extract the `bookId` like `[ 0,6,13]` as list. below code is not working for me.

```
import pandas as pd
data='''{
        "bookIds": [
            {
                "bookId": 0
            },
            {
                "bookId": 6
            },
            {
                "bookId": 13
            }]
    }'''


    df = pd.read_json(data)    
    print(df['bookIds']['bookId'])
```

Error

```
 raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'bookId'
```

How can I extract only bookID using datafarme?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_json` creates a single column DataFrame with dict values. You can use `str.get` to access the values in the dicts in the column `"bookIds"`:

```py
out = pd.read_json(data)['bookIds'].str.get('bookId').tolist()
```

Output:

```py
[0, 6, 13]
```